# PHP - bcadd not working when using variables

Tags: php

I'm simply trying to add two decimal numbers which are dynamic variables retrieved from a database.

Using `bcadd` works fine, but only if the parameters are not in the form of variables. See code below.

I've tested the two variables and they output the correct values, so the issue is not with the variables themselves.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$sqlogu = "SELECT oq_takeoff, oq_uplift FROM tbl_flights WHERE aircraft_id = 1 ORDER BY flight_id DESC LIMIT 1;";

$resultGU = $conn->query($sqlogu);

while ($rowGU = $resultGU->fetch_assoc()) { 

    $oq_takeoff_gu = $rowGU['oq_takeoff'];
    $oq_uplift_gu = $rowGU['oq_uplift'];

$ac_oil_gu = number_format($oq_takeoff + $oq_uplift, 2);

$test  = bcadd(2.00, 6.00, 2); // produces 8.00
$test2 = bcadd($oq_takeoff, $oq_uplift, 2); // produces 0.00

echo "Takeoff: " . $oq_takeoff_gu . "<br/>";
echo "Uplift: " . $oq_uplift_gu . "<br/>";
echo "Total: " . $ac_oil_gu . "<br/>";
echo "Test: " . $test;
echo "Test 2: " . $test2;

}
```

Comment: I don't see `$oq_takeoff` and `$oq_uplift` being defined at all? How did you test they have the correct values? (I only see `_gu` variants being defined)

Comment: Yep that's it. Thank you.

Comment: Just a typo, seriously, you must be out of coffee. :)

Comment: I've made this same mistake about 42 billion times, looking at the POST instead of the var i assigned it to -----  code'n aint easy yo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your

```
bcadd($oq_takeoff, $oq_uplift, 2)
```

isn't defined anywhere so it will always be zero, you might have forgot the_gu on the end of them

Comment: Yeah this was the issue, my bad! Will mark as correct, thanks.